# Hibernate subclass one-to-one mapping

Tags: hibernate, subclass, one-to-one

I have a complicated mapping that I believe should work. But why, after compiling, does the class A.d column seem to not exist?

```
public abstract Class A {
private Integer Id;
..
...
}

public Class SubA extend A {
   private D d;
}

public Class D {
   private SubA subA;
}

A.hbm.xml
<class name="A" table="A" abstract="true"/>

...

<subclass 
        name="SubA" 
        discriminator-value="SUB_A"
        lazy="false"
    >
        <join table="TABLE_SUB_A">
                <key column="ID"/>

            <many-to-one name="d" 
        column="COL_D" 
                class="D"
                cascade="NONE"
                outer-join="true"
                unique="true"/>
        </join>
   </subclass>
   </class>

D.hbm.xml
<one-to-one name="subA"
   class="SubA"
   property-ref="d"/>
```

Comment: You'd be better off reducing the mapping to the minimum amount required to reproduce the error and posting that, and also posting the exact error message you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't show discriminator column definition in `A` class, I'm assuming it's there. Also there's no "outer-join" attribute; it should be `fetch="outer-join"` instead.

Other then that, though, it looks OK - `d` property should be looked up on `subA`, not `A`. Are you sure you haven't changed anything when you've posted (I don't think you real entities are called `A` and `D`, so double check that you mapping is indeed as shown).

Also, why are you using discriminator for table-per-subclass? Using [joined-subclass](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/inheritance.html#inheritance-tablepersubclass) makes for easier mapping with no superfluous columns; the only advantage of discriminator is avoiding outer join on subclass tables which is usually not a big deal (plus you haven't specified `fetch="select"` on your subclass anyway)